# Function that adds equal amount of whitespace to both ends of string

Tags: javascript, function

```
function space(str,numSpace){
     str = "";
     numSpace = (" " + " ");
     document.write(numSpace + str + numSpace);
}
console.log(space("hi", " "));
```

This is not working out, I'm not too sure how I can add whitespace to both ends of a `string`.

Comment: well, line one you're overwriting the incoming string with "". Then in line two you make a string with two spaces, again, ignoring the value passed in .. and then in line 3 you travel back to the 1990's and `document.write` the 2 spaces, and empty string and 2 spaces - and you never return anything, so the `console.log` will log `undefined`

Comment: another thing to keep in mind, most web browsers collapse whitespace;  No matter if you enter 1 space or 1000, the browser will collapse them down to 1.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> This is not working out, i'm not too sure how I can add whitespace to
>   both ends of a string.

you're always resetting the parameter `str` to empty string hence the unexpected behaviour.

there are two ways you could solve the issue at hand.

1) you could use `console.log()` inside the method, example:

```
function space(str, numSpace) {
    var result = numSpace + str + numSpace;
    console.log(result);
}
space("hi", " ");
```

2) you could return the value then use `console.log()`:

```
function space(str, numSpace) {
    return numSpace + str + numSpace;
}
var result = space("hi", " ");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: `this.str = str;` - huh?

Answer (score -1):

Don't overwrite you're function's parameters with constants, and [don't use `document.write`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/802854/1048572) but `return` the result:

```
function space(str, numSpace) {
    return numSpace + str + numSpace;
}
console.log(space("hi", " "));
```

Also I would suggest renaming `numSpace` to `spaces`, as the former suggests to be used with an integer count, not a string of spaces.