# Adding equal amount of whitespace to both ends of string

Tags: javascript, function

```
    function space(str, numspace)
   {
       output="";
       for(i=0;i<str.length;++i)
       {
           output = numspace+ str;
       }
       for(i=0;i<str.length;++i)
       {
           output = output + numspace;
       }
       return output;
   }
```

I am trying to get this function to add an equal amount of whitespace to both ends of the string. I am not allowed to use built-in functions so that explains why i'm doing this the long way.

The output I get with the code I have :

space("hello","--")

"--hello-----------"

The "-" signify spaces, so the amount of spaces on the left side of the string is correct, but the amount of spaces on the right side of the string is way to much. Anyone have any ideas why this is occuring?

Comment: Shouldn't numspace be a number?

Comment: How are you supposed to decide how much space to add?

Comment: @James yes, it is

Comment: if only one reputation required, why do you use a for loop? simply return(sp+str+sp);

Comment: Then why is it `"--"` in your question?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43106709/2655623

Comment: Good question, I don't know why i put spaced there it's supposed to be a number, so when i input like 2 it returns "22hello22222222222" but i would like it to return spaces not the number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `numspace` is an integer, then you can use that value as the upper boundary in a for loop like so:

```js
function space(str, numspace)
{
    var emptySpace = "";
    for (i = 0; i < numspace; i++){
        emptySpace += " ";
    }
    var output = emptySpace + str + emptySpace;
    return output;
}

console.log("'" + space('example1', 5) + "'");
console.log("'" + space('example2', 3) + "'");
console.log("'" + space('example3', 1) + "'");
```

This way you'll create a variable `emptySpace` that is a string `numspace` in length of white space and attach it to the front and back of the `str` string before returning the output.

EDIT: Based on information from the comments of OP I have changed the function.

Comment: @TiagoSa Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do this instead:

```js
const space = (str, numspace) => {
    const spc = Array(numspace).fill(' ').join('')
    return spc+str+spc
}

console.log(space("ap", 3))
```

What it does:

- Create a `spc` variable which has as many spaces as `numspace` demands
- Join `spc` on both sides of `str`

#### Edit - The longer way

```js
const space = (str, numspace) => {
    let spc = ''
    for (;numspace--;spc+=' '){}
    return spc+str+spc
}

console.log(space('ap',3))
```

Comment: *"I am not allowed to use built-in functions so that explains why i'm doing this the long way."*

Comment: Edited with the longer way @Salivan

Comment: the question is not clear. if OP wants only one instance in both sides, why a loop needed?

Comment: This is a short and concise answer with good explanation. Downvoter pls reconsider!

Answer (score 0):

Just surround it with anything that you want to have in both side.

```
  function space(str, numspace)
   {
       output=str;
       for(i=0;i<str.length;++i)
       {
           output = numspace + output + numspace;
       }
       return output;
   }
```

Comment: Code dumps are not *useful* answers. Say *what* you changed, and *why*.

Answer (score 0):

This function can be used to append any number of characters to the text

```
    var output = addSpace('hello','*',4);
    alert(output); // output ****hello****

    function addSpace(text,character,no){
        var appendChar = character;
        for(var i=1;i<no;i++) {
        appendChar = appendChar+character;
      }
      return appendChar+text+appendChar;
    }
```